# Creating a button to change a boolean using htmx

Tags: django, button, boolean, htmx

I am trying to create a workflow using django and htmx were a user needs to accept an entry by clicking a button. In the backend this is supposed to change a boolean from `False` to `True`.

I followed this tutorial [HTMX 09 - Like e unlike com HTMX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl5T6Cut2hA) trying to adapt the "Like" functionality to my purposes, however in my case there is no template (at least non that makes sense to me) and this results in a 403 error. What is my error of thought here?

```
<models.py>
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Model
class PurchaseOrder(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

---

```
<views.py>
from .models import PurchaseOrder
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def po_accept(request, pk):
    order = get_object_or_404(PurchaseOrder, pk=pk)
    order.approved_accounting = True
    order.save()
    context = {'order': order}
    return render(request, context)


def my_approvals(request):
    orders = PurchaseOrder.objects.all()
    template = 'procurement/my_approvals.html'
    context = {'orders': orders}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

---

```
<urls.py>
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'procurement'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('my_approvals/', views.my_approvals, name='my_approvals'),
    path('po_accept/<int:pk>', views.po_accept, name='po_accept')
]
```

---

```
<my_approvals.html>

{% for order in orders %}
{{ order.name }}
<button 
   type="button" 
   class="btn btn-success m-3" 
   hx-post="{% url 'procurement:po_accept' order.pk %}"
   >
      Accept
   </button>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you set the `X-CSRFToken` header?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button 
   type="button" 
   class="btn btn-success m-3" 
   hx-post="{% url 'procurement:po_accept' order.pk %}"
   hx-headers="{ 'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}' }">
   Accept
</button>
```

Please include the CSRF token in the request headers using the hx-headers attribute in the button.Otherwise django will stop it for security reason.